# Seq - reverseMap vs reverse.map in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, seq

Why is there a method `reverseMap` on Seq in scala, when it appears to do the same as `reverse.map`?

Is one perhaps faster than the other?

Comment: Scaladoc for `reverseMap` states exactly that: "xs.reverseMap(f) is the same as xs.reverse.map(f) but might be more efficient.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For collections which can be efficiently iterated backwards (e.g. doubly-linked lists or indexable collections), `reverseMap` can potentially be more memory-efficient and time-efficient because `reverse` is type-preserving. I.e. if it is called on an array, it will create a copy of the array which is reversed, then `map` that array. (If `reverse` created reversed iterator instead of an array, things would be different.)

This requires O(n) extra space and iterates the array twice. Whereas `reverseMap` only iterates once and doesn't need extra space.

Unfortunately, it is not in general possible to leave such optimizations to the compiler. In particular, figuring out that `reverse.map` and `reverseMap` are the same is an instance of the *Function Problem*, which is undecidable.